# How to prove point is NOT a limit point? $E=\{\frac{4n-3}{2n-1}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, real-numbers

I've seen a bunch of questions showing how to prove a point is a limit point, but almost nothing showing that a point is NOT a limit point.
My definition of a limit point $x$ is that $\forall \epsilon >0, (B(x,\epsilon)\backslash\{x\})\cap E \neq  \emptyset$ where $B(x,\epsilon)$ is the ball centered in $x$ with radius $\epsilon$. Since we are in $\mathbb{R}$, $B(x,\epsilon)=]x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon[$.

Let $E=\{\frac{4n-3}{2n-1}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ be a set. How do I show that 5/3 is not a limit point? Intuitively I can see that points will not "accumulate" at 5/3, but how do I show this rigorously?

Comment: The sequence actually converges to $2$, so for large enough $n$, it stays away from $5/3$.

Comment: Prove $$\exists\epsilon >0, (B(5/3,\epsilon)\setminus \{5/3\})\cap E = \varnothing.$$

Comment: So you set $\epsilon < 1/3  $  where later find N where difference is smaller than this epsilon for all n >N asnsaid Focus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intuitively, a point is not a limit point of a sequence if its smallest  distance to an element of the sequence (not including itself) is a positive number. What $n$ minimizes $d=|\frac{4n-3}{2n-1}-5/3|?$

$\frac{4n-3}{2n-1}-5/3=\frac{12n-9-5(2n-1)}{3(2n-1)}=\frac{2(n-2 )}{3(2n-1)}$

$\frac{2(n-2 )}{3(2n-1)}=\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{2n-1}$

So $n=2\implies d=0$. So 5/3 is an element/point of the sequence.

$n=1\implies d=2/3$

$n=3\implies d=2/15$

$n=4\implies d=4/21$

More generally higher values of $n$ take d further away from 0. If it were a limit point, there would exist elements of the sequence "arbitrarily close" to 5/3, but there are no points closer than 2/15, not counting 5/3 itself.

We can move from intuition to the formal definition.

Let $\epsilon =1/15$.

$\forall n\in \mathbb N \backslash \{2\}, |5/3-\frac{4n-3}{2n-1}|>\epsilon$. This is in direct contradiction to a point being a limit point.

Note a corollary of the formal definition of a limit point is also that there are infinitely many points of a sequence within $\epsilon$ of a limit point, however small epsilon is. So if there are only finitely many points of the sequence near the possible limit point, then its not a limit point.

Answer (score 2):

Hints: Since $\frac {4n-3} {2n-2} \to 2$ we expect that $\frac {4n-3} {2n-2} >1.9$ for $n$ sufficiently large. Verify that this inequality is indeed true if $n>5$. Next note that $1.9 >\frac 5 3$. Can you now find an interval around $\frac 5 3$ which contains at most $5$ points of the given sequence?

Comment: Why $1.9$ and not $2$ and why sufficiently large $n$.  $\frac {4n-2}{2n-1} > 2$ for *all* $n$.  Also why "at most 5 points" we need to find an interval with *no* points (which, admittedly if there are finitely many we take a distance smaller than the closest)

Comment: If $x$ is a limit point of $A$ then every open neighborhood of $x$ contains **infinitely many points** of $A$. If there are only finitely many points we can further restrict the neighborhood so that there is no point of $A$ other than $x$ in that neighborhood. In this specific case you can find out how to retsrict the interval so that even the first $5$ points of the sequence are also avoided,.  If you try $2$ in place of $1.9$ you won't get strict inequality.  @fleablood

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, and following directly from your definition of "limit point," you just need to find a neighborhood of $x = \frac{5}{3}$ that does not intersect $E$ at any point other than possibly $x$ itself.

We claim that the neighborhood $B_d (x, \varepsilon)$ of $x$, where $\varepsilon = \frac{2}{15}$, intersects $E$ merely at $x$ itself. The set $E$ contains $3$ (for $n = 0$), $1$ (for $n = 1$), and $x = \frac{5}{3}$ (for $n = 2$). For $n \ge 3$, it is easy to see that

$$\frac{4 n - 3}{2 n - 1} = 2 - \frac{1}{2 n - 1} \ge \frac{9}{5}$$

The distance between $x$ and any *other* point of $E$ is therefore always greater than or equal to $\frac{9}{5} - \frac{5}{3} = \frac{2}{15}$, so that $B_d (x, \varepsilon) \cap E = \{x\}$. This shows that $x$ is not a limit point of $E$.

Answer (score 0):

Prove $$\exists\epsilon >0, (B(5/3,\epsilon)\setminus \{5/3\})\cap E = \varnothing.$$
Since $E$ consists of the numbers
$$1>\frac53>\frac95>\dots,$$
this condition on $\epsilon$ is equivalent to
$$\epsilon\le\min\left(\frac53-1,\frac95-\frac53\right)=\min\left(\frac23,\frac2{15}\right)=\frac2{15}.$$

Comment: @jauyjad: does your $\Bbb N$ contain $0$ or not? (I assumed it doesn't but I can change my answer if it does.)